# EditText is not showing what i am writing if i write a long line

Tags: android, android-layout

I made a layout like below but the problem is that when i write something long line is a editText - than the focus does not go with the cursor any more. I mean i cant see what i am writing if the lines get too long. What to do?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CityActivity"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayoutctentry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingRight="3dp"> 
    <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRowctyentry1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
              android:paddingRight="3dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/aTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cityNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

  <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRowctyentry2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="About" />
        <EditText
             android:id="@+id/cityAboutEditText"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:textSize="15dp" />
    </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove the `android:paddingRight="3dp"` also set  `android:textSize="15sp"` instead of dp

Comment: not yet, still working on it :-(

Comment: checkout my ans...then if you have any problem say me.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `android:textSize="15dp"` this in XML remove it and check. Try like below.

```
<EditText
             android:id="@+id/cityAboutEditText"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 />

 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cityNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

and also set your width and height to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.beginandroid.com/keyboard.shtml   in above link change just suggastion text

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

with

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

In both TextView.

So now your code should be

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CityActivity"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tableLayoutctentry"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:paddingRight="3dp"> 
<TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRowctyentry1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:paddingRight="3dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cityNameEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

 </TableRow>

<TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRowctyentry2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About" />
    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/cityAboutEditText"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:textSize="15dp" />
</TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this

`android:textSize="15dp"`

and use:

```
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 



<TextView
            android:id="@+id/aTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **android:singleLine="false"** into your **Edittext** XML and change **android:layout_width** from **wrap_content** to **fill_parent** as follows...

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cityAboutEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

You can't see your long typed text because by default, **android:singleLine** set to **true** when you didn't mention manually write it **android:singleLine="false"**.